# Send email with template (Mandrill PHP)

Tags: php, templates, mandrill

I have created a template in Mandrill but I don't know how to use to send email.

Here is an example how to use it with a simple html:

```
<?php

include_once "swift_required.php";

$subject = 'Hello from Mandrill, PHP!';
$from = array('you@yourdomain.com' =>'Your Name');
$to = array(
 'recipient1@example.com'  => 'Recipient1 Name',
 'recipient2@example2.com' => 'Recipient2 Name'
);

$text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
$html = "<em>Mandrill speaks <strong>HTML</strong></em>";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
$transport->setUsername('MANDRILL_USERNAME');
$transport->setPassword('MANDRILL_PASSWORD');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
 echo 'Message successfully sent!';
} else {
 echo "There was an error:\n";
 print_r($failures);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can send the email and use the template by using the [Mandrill PHP API wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php).

```
require 'Mandrill.php';

$mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');

$message = array(
    'subject' => 'My subject',
    'from_email' => 'marc@example.com',
    'to' => array(array('email' => 'recipient1@example.com', 'name' => 'Marc')),
    'merge_vars' => array(array(
        'rcpt' => 'recipient1@example.com',
        'vars' =>
        array(
            array(
                'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                'content' => 'Recipient 1 first name'),
            array(
                'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                'content' => 'Last name')
    ))));

$template_name = 'YOUR-TEMPLATE-NAME';

$template_content = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'main',
        'content' => 'Hi *|FIRSTNAME|* *|LASTNAME|*, thanks for signing up.'),
    array(
        'name' => 'footer',
        'content' => 'Copyright 2013.')

);

$response = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message);
print_r($response);
```

If you want to use the SMTP via SwiFtMailer, you could call the Render API method to render a template, which will give you the full HTML, which you can pass to SwiftMailer but that seems a bit of a long winded way of doing it compared to the PHP API wrapper.

Comment: thanks, its working, just a correction: $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');

Comment: one more info, I have set *|pspReference|* inside html template and in merge_vars I used: 'name' => 'pspReference',
                'content' => 'Hello world'), but it don't change the value, do you know why? thanks

Comment: i got this response {
status: 0,
message: "API call to messages/send-template failed: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
}

Comment: @HiteshModha, This issue is because your website needs to be under SLL certicate (HTTPS).